# Does $C$ commute with $A$ and $B$ if it commutes with $A+B$ and $AB$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$, $B$ $\in$ $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$. If $C$ $\in$ $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, such that $C$ commutes with $A+B$ and $AB$, does $C$ commutes with $A$ and $B$?

Do we need extra condition to prove the above? like eigen values of $A ,B$ are disjoint?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

If $A, B$ have disjoint eigenvalues, then using Sylvester's equation ($AX-XB =C$ has unique solution iff eigenvalues of $A, B$ are disjoint) we can prove.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is "no". Hint for constructing a counterexample: $C$ commutes with $0$ and $I$.

However, the answer is "yes" if $A$ and $B$ have disjoint spectra. This is known as Embry's theorem.